# Как использовать написанный мной template_tag с параметром в {% if else %}

Tags: python, django

Я написал тег для проверки существования переменной в контексте, он возвращает bool

```
@register.simple_tag(takes_context=True)
def is_exists(context, value):
    car = context['car']
    return bool(getattr(car, value, False))
```

Теперь мне нужно его каким-то образом использовать внутри {% if %}

```
{% if {%is_exists 'image_2'%} %}
       <li><a href="{{ car.image_2.url }}"><img src="{{ car.image_2.url }}" alt="Thumb Car" /></a></li>
{% endif %}
```

Не уверен, что это вообще возможно, но хотелось бы, чтобы это было правдой, потому-что хардкодить каждую переменную очень устал

```
Could not parse the remainder: '{%is_exists' from '{%is_exists'
```

Если написать вот так

```
                        {% if is_exists 'image_2' %}
                            <li><a href="{{ car.image_2.url }}"><img src="{{ car.image_2.url }}" alt="Thumb Car" /></a></li>
                        {% endif %}
```

То выпадает другая ошибка

```
TemplateSyntaxError at /4/
Unused ''image_2'' at end of if expression.
```

Comment: вероятно, `is_exists` – функция, так почему аргументы ей Вы передаёте не в скобках?

Comment: @V-Mor Было бы логично, не нет, скобки ничего не дают)